# How do I hear "shimmer"?

Tags: phonology, phonetics

[image: Jitter in praat]

How would you impressionistically guess if a voice has a high degree of "shimmer" (as opposed to a lot of "jitter").

I know these variable have to do with hoarseness or breathiness, but I have difficulty distinguishing one from the other.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @mateuz. As far as I'm aware, "shimmer" and "jimmer" aren't linguistic terms, so it's a bit difficult to grasp the meaning of this question. Could you maybe elaborate a little?

Comment: You bet. Shimmer and jitter are used in praat to characterize periodicity. I'll attach an image to illustrate.

Comment: ah thanks for enlightening me. I haven't used praat all that much and it was a while ago too

Comment: @DangerFourpence FYI these are not Praat-specific terms but rather standard terms that are widely used in speech pathology contexts. Jitter measures variability in periodicity, and shimmer measures variability in intensity from pulse to pulse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert on this, but results from a couple of studies I found suggest that you are not alone in your perceptual difficulties.

One study, outlined in an article by Meike Brockmann-Bauser, Paul N. Carding, and Michael J. Drinnan, entitled [*Do jitter and shimmer measure perceptual hoarseness?*](http://www.egms.de/static/en/meetings/dgpp2011/11dgpp26.shtml), compared perceptual assessments by voice experts to instrumental measurements of jitter and shimmer, and it found no clear correlation between either of those measures and degree of perceptual hoarseness:

> "Among pathologic voices, as measured by G of the GRBAS scale, there
>   was no clear association of jitter or shimmer with dysphonia severity.
>   Further it was not possible to reliably distinguish normal from
>   pathologic sounding voices by jitter or shimmer. Therefore we conclude
>   that neither jitter nor shimmer are an objective index of perceptual
>   hoarseness." (from the discussion section)

In another study carried out by Jody Kreiman and Bruce R. Gerratt (UCLA), the results of which are presented in a PowerPoint presentation entitled [*Jitter, Shimmer, and Noise in Pathological Voice Quality Perception*](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CDgQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.isca-speech.org%2Farchive_open%2Farchive_papers%2Fvoqual03%2Fpresentations%2Fvoq3_057.pps&ei=PZJbVOH7IpW_sQTgxoLICg&usg=AFQjCNHFdXl-KB4ukyxvNudKkvZRpMfPsQ&sig2=ETUk9KphLXJ3YSupTA0Kyw&bvm=bv.78677474,d.cWc&cad=rja), two experiments were carried out.  In the first experiment, subjects were presented with sample recordings of human voices with perceptual irregularities. For each stimulus, they were given the opportunity to control the settings for jitter, shimmer, and noise on a synthesized speech sample to match, as best as they could, the human sample. Their responses were highly variable when it came to jitter and shimmer, but more consistent when it came to noise. The experimenters posited two possible explanations:

> - Listeners may be insensitive to differences in the amounts of jitter and shimmer in a voice
> - Listeners may have difficulty determining which level is the correct response because they cannot separate jitter or shimmer
>     perceptually from the composite noise component.

In the second experiment, subjects were presented with a series of synthetic speech samples, which varied along various dimensions including degree of jitter, degree of shimmer, and degree of noise. Overall, subjects did quite poorly and distinguishing jitter and shimmer. They did marginally better when noise was absent (not a likely scenario in the real world), but even then their sensitivity was still "limited".

The presentation has many clickable sound clips, so you can hear examples of what the subjects heard.